# Is there a way to turn on/off a particular field from Django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I want to implement a setting in my Django admin dashboard where I can disable/enable a particular field. If I should disable the field, the data in that field will not be rendered on the web page. If I should enable the field, then the data will be shown in the webpage. I only want to do this from my the admin dashboard.

This is my `models.py`:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/')
    description = models.TextField()
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

This is the `admin.py`:

```
@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'category', 'slug', 'price', 'available')
    list_filter = ('category', 'available')
    list_editable = ('price', 'available')
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}
```

I want to have the ability to enable/disable (maybe like a toggle button) the `description` field from my admin dashboard. Is there a way to implement this in my `admin.py` file? How can I go about this? Thanks.

**Edit**: For better understanding (as suggested the comment), I want to implement a master toggle in the admin dashboard which turns on/off all descriptions for every instance shown to the user.

Comment: This seems a little unclear. Do you want to toggle whether or not the field is visible in the Django admin like a collapsing element, or do you want an extra field on the model which determines if the user can see that instance's description in your HTML template, or do you want a master toggle which turns off all descriptions for every instance shown to the user?

Comment: it is also unclear for me. If you want to hide/show on dashboard when you visit this dashoboard then maybe you should use JavaScript to toggle HTML and keep this starte in cookies. If you want to use dashboard to hide it when other users visit pages then it may need other table for settings and it will need to use these settings when you render HTML for other users.

Comment: @Jacinator the latter part of your comment is exactly what I want to achieve. A master toggle in the admin dashboard which turns on/off all descriptions for every instance shown to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

First, add this field to your `models.py`:

```
is_description = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Then make migrations:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Then you can add the following customization to your `admin.py`:

- override the `get_urls` method and add the `enable_description` and `disable_discription` methods on the model admin. They will serve as the two view methods:

  ```
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        my_urls = [ 
            path('descriptionon/', self.enable_description),
            path('descriptionoff/',self.disable_discription),
        ]
        return my_urls + URLs 

    def enable_description(self, request):
        self.model.objects.all().update(is_description=True)
        self.message_user(request, "All descriptions are now turned on")
        return HttpResponseRedirect("../") 

    def disable_description(self, request):
        self.model.objects.all().update(is_description=False)
        self.message_user(request, "All descriptions are now turned on")
        return HttpResponseRedirect("../")
  ```

Next, you need to override your Django admin template by creating a template file `product_changelist.html` and then extend `admin/change_list.html`:

```
{% extends 'admin/change_list.html' %}

{% block object-tools %}
    <div>
        <form action="descriptionoff/" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit">Turn description on</button>
        </form>
        <form action="descriptionoff/" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit">Turn description off</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <br />
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

Visit your admin dashboard for your `Product` model. You should now see the two buttons above the search bar.

Finally, in your `views.py` add this logic:

```
def product_list(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    for product in products.iterator():    
    if product.is_description:
        return render(request,
                      'product_list.html',
                      {'product': products})
    disable_descp = product.__class__.objects.all().values('category', 'name', 'image',...)

    return render(request,
                  'product_list.html',
                  {'product': disable_descp})
```

When you click on `Turn description on` in your admin dashboard and refresh your template page, the descriptions will be available. It will not be available if you click on `Turn description off` in your admin dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

The [Django constance](https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance) (no association to myself) might do what you want. It doesn't necessarily store the toggle you're describing in any way connected to your model, but it will allow you to have editable settings. This can be used in your form definition or passed to your context through either the view or a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors).

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to do so.

1 permission to admin user.
2 bool show or not to Object.
3 New Admin view.

## 1

You may add a permission to see this field and create a method in admin.py to see it or return None depending on permission value.

In admin.py in

```
class YourAdminClass(admin.ModelAdmin)
    def get_queryset(self, request):
         queryset= super(YourAdminClass, self).get_queryset(request)
         self.request = request
         return queryset 

    def mobile_phone(self, obj):
        return obj.user.mobile_phone if self.request.user.has_special_permission else None
```

## 2

You may add a bool to the object instead of permission to user (show or do not show in admin) and change the query set as in option 1 (this way you may control it from the client side FE)

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(YourAdminClass, self).get_queryset(request)
    return qs.filter(SHOW_MY_FIELD=True)
```

## 3

Create anew Admin view NoFieldAdmin and alternative to Admin and show or not show the link in main admin via the admin url
in main admin.py file

```
class NoFieldAdminSite(AdminSite):
    pass
    #or overwrite some methods for different functionality

NoFieldAdmin= NoFieldAdminSite(name="nofield_admin")   

in urls.py
        urlpatterns = [
            url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
            url(r'^NOFIELD-admin/', NoFieldAdmin.urls),
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but this doesn't affect the front end. The data is still being reflected in the front-end. How do I do  it such that changes in the admin will also be reflected in the template without having to edit the template or views?

Comment: JS - but it can be hacked by the admin user ...